# Need solution for report generation mechanism

Tags: spring-mvc, web-applications, talend, reportgenerator

I have one issue. Actually we have one spring-mvc web based application , for which we want report generation mechanism. I came across Talend ETL. Can anyone tell whether to use talend as report generation mechanism will be fruitful. Can i integrate it with my application ? Or whether i should search for some jar that can help in fast report generation mechanism.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is vague, but let me try to answer anyway. Talend is not a reporting platform, but an ETL (read: data handling and transformation) tool.

You can embed a TOS job in your application, and it'sadvisable to do if you need to handle data in a medium/complex way without reinventing the wheel (ie. read an Excel file, do some things, save on DB...). But use it as reporting or data visualization platform would be a pain in the neck.

There're better embeddable solutions for these duties. Birt and JasperReports come in mind, but there's plenty of them. The real question for choosing from is: do you need a low-level reporting service, not much more than a framework at the end of the day, or a polished, maybe client-server, solution to query as a service?

Comment: Hi, Apologizing for such vague question. Kindly tell me one thing, I need to create the some xls reports , containing some transaction data, that includes nested queries from multiple tables and multiple DB. Now Will it be useful to use Talend , or i can have some better solution?

Comment: you absolutely can, but don't expect too much power from the xls output components :)